# ! Undefined control sequence on tables

Tags: tables, graphics, pdftex

I am new in LaTeX.
I have created LaTeX and Gnuplot to build my graphs. Currently I have to add new table using LaTeX. but I get error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.60 \mycaption
               {tab-comp}{Table Component}{
```

This is my LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{eps/a1-count}
\includegraphics{eps/a2-type}
\includegraphics{eps/a2-typereal}
\includegraphics{eps/a3-aspect}
\input{tab-comp/tab-comp}
\end{document}
```

I guess this because missing package in LaTeX, but I don't have Idea what are the packages. Anyone who know about this? Thanks!

Comment: What is `\mycaption`? latex doesn't know it.

Comment: Without knowing the content of the `\input` file, we can't tell.  But I would assume that some code in it contains the macro `\mycaption` and that hasn't been defined anywhere.

Comment: @HarishKumar,yes the error happen because \caption.  But I have see the other reference using \mycation to create caption of table.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Check your reference, then, and see how `\mycaption` is defined. You need to add that to your code before you can use it.

Comment: The standard command is `\caption`  just use that unless you have a good reason not to.